# MTB Tire performance

Tags: mountain-bike, tire

I have always ridden a Mountain Bike and lately I've lived with a strange question related to the tire I've been using. I use a pair of 26 x 1.95 CST Rush tires that are a great cost-benefit and found easily in my country for $20 or less.

However, after a few minutes of riding on the road, it feels like the rear tire is being emptied. A few minutes after, this feeling passes and the trip remains normal, with great performance on the road and no complaints about the performance of the tire. This is normal behavior?

Comment: Do you notice a difference going the other way - starting on the road and then going off-road?

Comment: Generally i make every trip on a same terrain type, but this _problem_ occurs in both road or land track

Comment: Can you elaborate? When you say it feels like the tire is being emptied, is there a noise or does it just feel slow? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow you exactly, but I ride road and dirt. More to it, I ride my mountain bike on the road on the way to the dirt. Here's my $0.02.

The [tires on my mountain bike](http://www.panaracer.com/eng/products/mtb/xc.html#e) are inflated to about 32-35 PSI (2.2-2.4 bars), and they have a lot of rolling resistance on asphalt. The sensation of riding on them is entirely different than my road bike tires, which are typically inflated to 105-110 psi (7.2-7.6 bars). The mountain bike tires feel like they are flat, even when I know they are not. I find myself looking down at them, wondering if they are still holding air. In my defense, on the mountain bike, I use tubes filled with a sealant, so it is possible for a puncture-- a thorn, maybe, or a piece of wire from a car tire-- to cause a slow leak. When you pull the thorn or wire out, there is a little puff of air that escapes, but the sealant usually closes the leak almost immediately. But it is not foolproof, and I can't shake the feeling the tires feel flat, even if I just aired them up before riding.